# Remove a folder inside a symlink

Tags: linux, ubuntu, symbolic-link

Having a symlink:

`ln -s /var/www /media/Disk2/dropbox/www`

How can I remove a folder from the symlink located at `/media/Disk2/dropbox/www/test` without afecting the main folder?

Comment: Are you saying you want to remove `/media/Disk2/dropbox/www/test` without removing `/var/www/test`? That's not possible, they are one and the same folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, a symlink is just a file containing a pointer to the other folder(subdirectory).